# const declaration - How to evaluate expressions at compile time?

Tags: go, constants

In the below code:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func area(r float64, shapeConstant float64, result *float64) error {
    if r <= 0 {
        return errors.New("r must be positive")
    }
    *result = shapeConstant * r * r
    return nil
}

const (
    shapeConstantForSquare  = 1.0
    shapeConstantForCircle  = math.Pi
    shapeConstantForHexagon = 3 * math.Sqrt(3) / 2         // 3 * 1.73205080757 / 2
)

func areaOfSquare(r float64, result *float64) error {
    return area(r, shapeConstantForSquare, result)
}

func areaOfCircle(r float64, result *float64) error {
    return area(r, shapeConstantForCircle, result)
}

func areaOfHexagon(r float64, result *float64) error {
    return area(r, shapeConstantForHexagon, result)
}

func main() {
    var result float64
    err := areaOfSquare(3, &result)
    display(err, &result)
    areaOfCircle(3, &result)
    display(err, &result)
    areaOfHexagon(3, &result)
    display(err, &result)
}

func display(err error, result *float64) {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(*result)
}
```

---

`const shapeConstantForHexagon = 3 * math.Sqrt(3) / 2` needs runtime to evaluate expression(RHS) and provide value to LHS. Compile error.

How to avoid expression evaluation in RHS, at runtime? in const declaration

Does below expression evaluation lose precision?

```
const(
    sqrtOfThree             = 1.73205080757
    shapeConstantForHexagon = 3 * sqrtOfThree / 2 
)
```

Comment: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Constant_expressions